# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I am new to the tkinter and trying out a simple Tkinter GUI, but getting error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib

master = Tk()
master.title("Demo GUI")
master.geometry("900x400+150+150")
master.resizable(0,0)

def browse_file():
    global file_path
    global data_frame
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Choose the file to upload")
    data_frame = pd.read_excel(file_path)

Label = Label(master,text="Choose the file to upload").grid(row=0)

Button = Button(master,text='Browse',command = browse_file).grid(row=0,column=1,pady=4)

Label_1 = Label(master,text="The file selected: "+file_path).grid(row=1,column=0)

master.mainloop()
```

The error that I am getting is,

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-451372edd65a> in <module>
     25 Button = Button(master,text='Browse',command = browse_file).grid(row=0,column=1,pady=4)
     26 
---> 27 Label1 = Label(master,text="The file Choosen: "+file_path).grid(row=1,column=0)
     28 
     29 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101765/7414759)

Comment: You are setting `Label` to `None`, and then trying to create a label using `Label(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The error you did is a typo: By writing:

```
Label = Label(master,text="Choose the file to upload").grid(row=0)
```

You assign the result of the `grid` call to the original tk.Label type (`Label`). gird return call is `None`

So then when you try to create the Label1 you are in practice calling Label which is now `None`

Simply replace the line by:

```
 l = Label(master,text="Choose the file to upload")
 l.grid(row=0)
```

or simply

```
Label(master,text="Choose the file to upload").grid(row=0)
```

Comment: There's no point in doing `l =` since all you're doing is assigning it the value of `None`.

Answer (score 0):

'NoneType' object is not callable error is caused by placing object where it is defined.
So instead of

```
Label_1 = Label(master,text="The file selected: "+file_path).grid(row=1,column=0)
```

Try:

```
Label(master,text="The file selected: "+file_path).grid(row=1,column=0)
```

Or

```
Label_1 = Label(master,text="The file selected: "+file_path)
Label_1.grid(row=1,column=0)
```

Also do not use Button = Button(master... rather give a unique name to variable

Answer (score 0):

This is answer:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib

master = Tk()
master.title("Demo GUI")
master.geometry("900x400+150+150")
master.resizable(0,0)

def browse_file():
    global file_path
    global data_frame
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Choose the file to upload")
    data_frame = pd.read_excel(file_path)

Label = Label(master,text="Choose the file to upload").grid(row=0)

Button = Button(master,text='Browse',command = browse_file).grid(row=0,column=1,pady=4)

Label_1 = tk.Label(master,text="The file selected: "+file_path).grid(row=1,column=0)

master.mainloop()
```